# Windows 10 mshta.exe FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-10

I have changed the registy from : 
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION\mshta.exe` 
 to 
 8000, 9000, 10000, 11000 or 11001 etc but `mshta.exe` always works as IE7. 
I don't have problems with Windows XP or 7, but only with Windows 10.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Compatibility

Comment: Thanks ! Now all works fine.